# Hi! I'm not able to connect with "heroku redis" on django

Tags: django, heroku, redis, celery, periodic-task

I've followed all the steps in the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvYo6LBZUh8&t=166s

However, I'm not able to connect with "heroku redis", I am using celery to implement periodic tasks. The error is the following:

> [2021-04-02 22:00:05,622: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect
> to redis://:**@ec2-54-160-13-161.compute-1.amazonaws.com:12880//:
> Error while reading from socket:  (10054, 'Se ha forzado la
> interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto', None,
> 10054, None).

So, any idea of what could be happening would be great. ¡Thank you so much!

Comment: in my case, it was working fine for some 2 3 weeks. But today it is showing this error.

Comment: @RahulHindocha Heroku keeps changing the URI so run `heroku redis:credentials REDIS_URL` like Marcos Paolo said and get the updated REDIS_URL.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good practice to set your redis URL in settings.py with OS `os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')`

Heroku rotates credentials periodically and updates applications where this datastore is attached.

Heroku recommends using encryption and thus a `rediss://` URL instead of `redis://`

For celery, something like: CELERY_BROKER_URL = `'rediss://:{Password}@{Host}:{Port}'`

Heroku command to get this url easy `heroku redis:credentials REDIS_URL`

Referer: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#using-the-cli